# Need my EF core to see already existing primary key in my SQL server table and work with it

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a SQL server DB table namely "RSBFileDetails", which has a primary key column "[File_Reference_Id]" auto generated int type. When I run my code to enter values in my DB using EF, I get an error: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to track an instance of type 'RsbfileDetail' because it does not have a primary key. Only entity types with primary keys may be tracked.'"

My code to enter data is:

```
public async void PostValuesIntoDB()
    {
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path);          
        FileInfo[] fileInfos = info.GetFiles("*.trm");
        if (fileInfos != null || fileInfos.Length>0)
        {
            foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileInfos)
            {
                RsbfileDetail detail = new RsbfileDetail();
                detail.Filename = fileInfo.Name;
                detail.FileUrl = fileInfo.FullName;
                detail.FileType = fileInfo.Extension;                   
                detail.CreatedDate = fileInfo.CreationTime;                   
                await _rSBRepository.Add(detail);
            }
        }
```

await statement creates error message. I am new to coding and EF so please help me with this. My Model is:

```
      public partial class RsbfileDetail
{
    public string FileUrl { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string CaseId { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int FileReferenceId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string FileId { get; set; }
    public string Preset { get; set; }
    public string TranscodeCallbackUrl { get; set; }
    public string FileTranscodeJobId { get; set; }
    public string TranscriptionCallbackUrl { get; set; }
    public string JobDefinition { get; set; }
    public string TranscriptionJobId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your Exception is saying that your model doesn't have a primary key defined. You need to update your model either by using the `[key]` attribute or with the fluent API stating that `File_Reference_Id` is the key. It would be helpful for you to share your model.

Comment: Hi Jerry, I have shared my model just now. I have added the [key] attribute in it but still have the same issue. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF uses naming conventions such as `Id` or `EntityNameId` when determining the default primary key. If you don't follow these conventions you can mark your primary key with the `[Key]` attribute.

```
public partial class RsbfileDetail
{
    // other properties

    [Key]
    public int FileReferenceId { get; set; }
    
    // other properties
}
```

Also, make sure that you haven't explicitly set your model to have no key in the fluent API. The exception that is thrown when you don't have a key defined kind of hints that using `.HasNoKey()` will magically fix that exception, however it will cause another one later.

Only use `.HasNoKey()` if your entity *truely* has no key, which is unlikely.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Remove this if it exists
    modelBuilder.Entity<RsbfileDetail>().HasNoKey(); // DELETE!

    ...

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jerry. I have tried it but still I have the same error message.

Comment: You didn't by chance call `builder.Entity<RsbfileDetail>().HasNoKey()` in your model builder did you?

Comment: Hi Jerry. I have not used HasNoKey() anywhere in my model or code. but when I am autogenerating model from DB, there is no Primary key for this table. I thought [Key] should solve this issue. I am unable to find a solution for this issue.

Comment: If you are generating the code and there is no key then I would check the table in your database to see if the key is defined properly.

Comment: Found the .HasNoKey() in my context, I commented it and ran the code. Now there is no error.

Comment: Great to hear Deepak! Remember to check your DB though, if the key isn't properly defined there then the next exception you will get an exception when you try to save an entry to your database.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, The entry is happening fine right now. Thanks for all the help and  suggestions.